# Dividing SConstruct code into set of aliases; no code called by default

Tags: python, scons, build-tools

I'm trying to divide up my SConstruct file into blocks of code, where each block
is controlled by an Alias, and no code is run by default; i.e. just by running`scons`.
The Aliases are of course run from the command line e.g. (in the example below):

```
scons h
```

Here is some example code. This appears to work Ok. However, three questions.

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. More specifically, I don't understand how the target arguments in the Alias call 
   get passed to the `h` and `h3` action functions. I notice if I leave them blank the
   build does not work. However there is no obvious way for the targets to be passed
   to these functions, since they do not take any arguments.
3. Relatedly, the documentation says that action functions requires `target`, `source`,
   and `env` arguments. These action functions don't have these but work anyway. How come?

Code follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                         

Default(None)

def h(env):
    x = env.Program("hello1", "hello1.c")
    y = env.Program("hello2", "hello2.c")
    return 0

def h3(env):
    y = env.Program("hello3", "hello3.c")
    return 0

env = Environment()
env.AddMethod(h, "HELLO")
env.AddMethod(h3, "HELLO3")
env.Alias("h", ["hello1", "hello2"], env.HELLO())
env.Alias("h3", ["hello3"],env.HELLO3())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: yes, there is a better way.

```
env = Environment()

# h:
x = env.Program("hello1", "hello1.c")
y = env.Program("hello2", "hello2.c")
env.Alias("h", [x,y])
# equivalently: env.alias("h", ["hello1", "hello2"])

# h3
y = env.Program("hello3", "hello3.c")
env.Alias("h3", y)

Default(None)
```

Alternatively, if you like grouping your `Program()` calls in a subroutine, that's okay, too. You just don't need `AddMethod()` for what you're doing:

```
env = Environment()

def h(env):
    x = env.Program("hello1", "hello1.c")
    y = env.Program("hello2", "hello2.c")
    return x,y

def h3(env):
    return env.Program("hello3", "hello3.c")

env.Alias("h", h(env))
env.Alias("h3", h3(env))
Default(None)
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that was a more sensible way to go. Actually, that is the way that `Alias` is supposed to be used. Except that I didn't use the return value of `env.Program` in `Alias`. I used the actual target. Is there some advantage in using the return value? I suppose it would save having to change things in Alias if the targets change. Also, presumably, the return value could stand in for multiple return targets if they were used in e.g. `Program`.

Comment: You have listed all of the advantages that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks Rob. That was a very helpful answer.